# How do I delete SQL Server rows based on the certain characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server Express table called `tabl1` which contains 20,000 rows (the table has only one column called `phone_numbers`).

The `phone_numbers` column has mobile phone numbers and landline numbers.

How can I delete (using a SQL query) all rows starting with `0151` in the `phone_numbers` column?

Comment: Since every DB engine uses a different SQL dialect, which one are you using?

Comment: Look into substring functions (which vary from database to database).  delete from tbl where left(phone,4) = '0151' could work pending your database.

Comment: @juergen d. MS sql server express

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch entries starting with the given string from a SQL Server database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345988/how-to-fetch-entries-starting-with-the-given-string-from-a-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this if the phone_numbers are stored as strings :

```
delete from tabl1
where phone_numbers like '0151%'
```

Hope this helps!!!